# Google visualization gauge in vertical alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I want to put google gauge in vertical alignment. This is my javascript code (it's copy paste from google playground)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Memory', 80],
          ['CPU', 55],
          ['Network', 68]
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 400, height: 120,
          redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
          yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('menu2'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

And this is my html div

```
<div id="menu2"></div>
```

and css

```
#menu2
{
background-color:#FFD700;
height:570px;
width:150px;
float:right;
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added inline style to div in which gauge will load. Ans removed all width height options from script given my google.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NB3Eg/

You can play with its html & css here https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#gauge

Comment: I can't get it to work. Here is my div `<div id="visualization" style="height: 570px; width: 150px;"></div>` and css `#visualization
{
background-color:#7AD7F9;
float:right;
}`

Comment: how is this possible. You got it to work and I keep getting them horizontal

Comment: Please put your final code on jsfiddle.net & share with me. I want to see where you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Its same what i sent to you. I want your code. Make a new fiddle.

Comment: I will put my example that I was looking on the JSfiddle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12215/discussion-between-denonth-and-surendra-vikram-singh)